# neard(-tools) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, nfc

I'm trying to install the `neard` package in Ubuntu 20.04.
[Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/neard-tools/0.16-0.1) I read:

> Status: Superseded

But it does not say "superseded" by what.
Anyway I tried to download the `deb` package (translated from Italian):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb 
dpkg-deb: error: "neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb" it is not an archive in Debian format
dpkg: error when processing archive neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control has returned error 2
```

I tried to find the newer package

```
$ apt-cache search neard
$
```

The goal is to use the Qt5 NFC module that requires `neard`.

### EDIT

I hope I don't need `neard` but in the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qtnfc-index.html) I read:

> Currently the API is supported on Android, and Linux using Neard v0.14 or later.

Are you sure I don't need it?

Comment: See below answer about *neard*. But are you sure you really need it? I see https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libqt5nfc5 in the repository, it does not depend on *neard*.

Comment: @N0rbert see my edit. Are you sure I really don't need it? :-)

Comment: On focal you will get Qt 5.12 from official packages. If you plan to widely distribute your possibly great application then it is recommended to use Qt version which is shipped with Ubuntu distribution. What is interesting [docs for 5.12](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtnfc-index.html) also mention neard, so you can try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to install *neard* packages https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/neard-tools from supported Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repository manually as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/neard/neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/neard/neard-tools_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb ./neard-tools_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
```

Installation from *proposed* is possible from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/neard/0.16-0.1/+build/11887550  as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/neard/0.16-0.1/+build/11887550/+files/neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/neard/0.16-0.1/+build/11887550/+files/neard-tools_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./neard_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb ./neard-tools_0.16-0.1_amd64.deb
```

but I can't find the reason for this.

Comment: Ok, but in 20.04 the package is superseeded by what?

Comment: I'm not sure. Reported [bug 1951107](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/neard/+bug/1951107).